WiFi Calling is not reliably available
WiFi Calling is not reliably available on my Android phone. Sometimes it disappears and requires turning airplane mode on and off to re-appear. Rarely a phone restart may be required.
It is also unreliable when changing between, for example, home and work WiFi. The networks are different, both good quality, but frequently WiFi calling will work in only one of them.
Any ideas what might be causing this? The issue appears on two Xiaomi phones I have, same carrier. Phones are Redmi 9C NFC and Redmi Note 8 Pro.

The WiFi standard is evolving over time. May be the different Wifis implement different WiFi versions and features? The last few WiFi versions had many improvements for device stand-by without loosing connectivity. That can make a difference for a system that always needs to be connected like WIFI calling (for receiving calls in background).

I've done some experiments with the "Wi-Fi Scan Throttling" option in Developer settings. It is enabled by default. I tried disabling it and it seems it has made wifi calling almost perfect. To verify that was the cause, I re-enabled it, but the issue remains fixed! Wifi calling still works. Maybe turning that off and on "unblocked" it or something.

WiFi Scan Throttling can only have an effect if there are multiple Wifi around and you need to change the access point. Anyway the Wifi calling program is a system app and thus AFAIK not affected by this setting. May there was a problem on carrier side that is now fixed.

From some google searching it seems throttling affects system apps and services too. Maybe the wifi calling service needs to assess the quality of the network and it needs to poll that data to do it? Also I doubt the carrier fixed the issue, I've been dealing with it for months.

The quality of a Wifi network you are connected with doesn't have to be scanned. Scanning is for detecting Wifi APs you are not connected with. Thus it may have an effect if you are in a Wifi network with multiple APs (e.g. public or corporate Wifi networks for whole buildings) as it would simplify selecting the best AP.

I don't have multiple APs, just one.

After playing around with the "WiFi Scan Throttling" option in Developer Options, I have determined that it does make a difference. WiFi calling sometimes struggles to connect with Scan Throttling enabled.
If you face the same issue, write in the comments if disabling Scan Throttling fixes it.
